# Apache not serving H2

Tags: apache, http, debian, h2, tls1.2

This morning I worked on making all my websites work through HTTPS, and I wanted to use that opportunity to switch to HTTP2.

My server is running Debian 8. I have updated Apache to 2.4.29 to get H2 support.

I have created TLS certificates for all my domains and they all are working fine (TLS 1.2, created using letsencrypt)

I think everything is configured right for apache to serve in H2 but for some reason I only get the HTTP/1.1 protocol.

I have enabled the http2 apache module:

```
a2enmod http2
```

I also have created a http2.conf (which I also have enabled) that contains the following information:

```
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1

H2Push          on
H2PushPriority  *                       after
H2PushPriority  text/css                before
H2PushPriority  image/jpeg              after   32
H2PushPriority  image/png               after   32
H2PushPriority  application/javascript  interleaved

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite 'EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS'
```

Source: https://www.shivering-isles.com/http-2-getting-ready-on-debian-with-apache2/

I also tried not using this conf file and adding "Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1" in the main apache conf file, or in virtual hosts, but it's still the same.

Any idea why Apache is serving HTTP/1.1 instead of H2?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running apache2 with mpm_event?
Then you also need to enable the fastcgi handler for PHP, activate the configuration for the PHP-fpm and disable the PHP apache2 module.

Your commands would be something like this:

```
root@host:/etc/apache2# a2dismod php7.2 
root@host:/etc/apache2# a2enmod proxy proxy_fcgi
root@host:/etc/apache2# a2enconf php7.2-fpm
root@host:/etc/apache2# a2dismod mpm_prefork 
root@host:/etc/apache2# a2enmod mpm_event
Enabling module mpm_event.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
systemctl restart apache2

root@host:/etc/apache2# systemctl restart apache2
```

Replace the PHP version number (I use 7.2) with your version. There's some deeper config settings for the PHP fcgi configuration if you need that let me know in the comments.